# what does Artifacts mean in Jeninks

Tags: jenkins

I need to use Jenkins in my company. And I am starting to learn it. I feel lost with all those videos.

I have come across the artifact when learning Jenkins, and I don't understand the meaning

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/93stoMa

Answer (score 1):

It is up to you what you promote as an artifact. It is usually something that you want to use later on.

> The definition of an artifact from Jenkins themselves is: an artifact is an immutable file, generated during a Build or Pipeline run in Jenkins. These artifacts are then archived onto the Jenkins Controller for later use.

[https://blog.inedo.com/jenkins/dont-store-build-artifacts-in-jenkins/#:~:text=The%20definition%20of%20an%20artifact,Jenkins%20Controller%20for%20later%20use](https://blog.inedo.com/jenkins/dont-store-build-artifacts-in-jenkins/#:%7E:text=The%20definition%20of%20an%20artifact,Jenkins%20Controller%20for%20later%20use).